# Can I add views in a layout that are only visible in the design preview?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a layout containing an empty LinearLayout. I fill the LinearLayout with child views dynamically at runtime. Is there any way in which I could preview the layout in Android studio as if those child views were already in the layout XML?

Basically as you can use tools namespace to show a differen preview (`tools:text="blabla"`) I would need something where the entire view would be under "tools" namespace so it would not be inside the app.

The idea I got was to add a view in XML, make it `android:visibility="gone"` and `tools:visibility="visible"` but I'm not sure is this a good approach? I wouldn't want to suddenly have double the rendering inside the app when it runs.

Comment: so what I understand, you want to add a view through programmatically and then want to handle its visibility. right ?

Comment: Not quite, I want to preview the final layout with dynamically added views in the Android Studio preview. But since the views will be added at runtime, I only get the preview with the empty container where the views will be added at runtime.